# An asked question, looking for more info. Find ${A} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -11 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let ${A}$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix such that
${A} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 7 \\ -13 \end{pmatrix}, \quad {A} \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 0 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}, \quad {A} \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -9 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \\ -11 \end{pmatrix}$
Find ${A} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -11 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.$
This is my hint : We know the result when 3 certain vectors are multiplied by A. Can we find a way to express  $ \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -11 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ that lets us use that information?
I don't get it. I don't know what a linear combination, I don't know how the last vector relates to the first 3. Can I get some explanation for this?

Comment: Yes, that's a right way. Another possible way is: can you compute $A$ given the equation $AB=C$ while $B,C$ are $3\times 3$ matrices?

Comment: **Hint** Use that $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -11\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}-2  \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -9 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}. $

Comment: @mfl post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could easily write :

$2{A} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 14 \\ -26 \end{pmatrix}, \quad -2{A} \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 0 \\ -8 \end{pmatrix}, \quad 1{A} \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -9 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \\ -11 \end{pmatrix}$

and at last factorin $A$ and adding given matrixs:

$ A(\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 8 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix}  + \begin{pmatrix} -8 \\ -10 \\ -12 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -9 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}) =\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 14 \\ -26 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 0 \\ -8 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \\ -11 \end{pmatrix} $

so finally:
$A \begin{pmatrix} 6-8+5 \\ 8-10-9 \\ 10-12+1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 4+12+3 \\ 14+0+3 \\ -26-8-11 \end{pmatrix} $

Answer (score 1):

As $\left\{ v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\4\\5 \end{pmatrix},v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 4\\5\\6 \end{pmatrix},v_3=\begin{pmatrix} 5\\-9\\1 \end{pmatrix}  \right\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3.$ So you can write any vector $\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ as linear combination of the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Let $\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c \end{pmatrix}= \alpha v_1+\beta v_2+\gamma v_3$ where $\alpha, \beta,\gamma\in \mathbb{R}.$ Then $$ A\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c \end{pmatrix}=A(\alpha v_1+\beta v_2+\gamma v_3)=\alpha A(v_1)+\beta A(v_2)+\gamma A(v_3). $$ Now since you know the values of $Av_1,Av_2,Av_3$ so you can compute the value of $A\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}.$

In your problem, as @mfI suggested 
\begin{align*}
& \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -11\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}-2  \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -9 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\\ 
\implies& A\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -11\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 7 \\ -13 \end{pmatrix}-2  \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 0 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \\ -11 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}19\\17\\-45\end{pmatrix} \end{align*}